# How to let the UI update automatically after a variable is updated in Dart (Not Flutter)?

Tags: dart, console-application

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:dart_console/dart_console.dart';

class Init extends ConsoleViewModel {
  String title;

  //Console
  Console console;

  Init(Console aConsole) {
    console = aConsole;
    this.redraw();
  }

  redraw() {
    console.clearScreen();
    console.setBackgroundColor(ConsoleColor.blue);
    console.setForegroundColor(ConsoleColor.white);
    console.writeLine(title, TextAlignment.center);
    console.resetColorAttributes();

    console.writeLine();
  }
}
```

I can change the title, and call redraw all the time, but is this possible to let it call redraw automatically instead of call it manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a **Function**, and you call it manually when the value of the variable changed

```
Function onChange = Function ();
```

But I don’t know where to use it

You can also benefit from this:

[PublishSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/PublishSubject-class.html)